# Installing a package program ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation

I want to install an engineering program (`spring_free`) on linux ( http://spring.delta-h.de/index.php/en/download-support), but I don't know how to do that.

There is an install file in the folder, although I am not familiar how to run it. In the installation there are some batch files, but I don't know how to use them. I would be grateful if you help me in this regards.

[image: Installation files in the folder]

Comment: Have you already tried to a open a terminal in that directory and run `./install`?

Comment: I'd suggest to ask the nice people at http://spring.delta-h.de/index.php/de/kontakt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Comment: yeah. it is installed with ./install command. thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Right click install.sh, click "Permissions" find "Allow executing file as  program", OK, and double click and run in terminal when asked.